# Wait for signal, then continue execution

Tags: c, linux, timer, signals, wait

I am trying to make a program that **suspends** its execution **until a signal arrives**. Then, after the signal arrives I just want my code to **continue its execution from where it was**. I don't want it to execute a function handler or whatsoever. Is there a simple way of doing this? I have been struggling for a week or so, reading here and there, and didn't manage to get a fully operative code.

In particular, I want the main program to **create a thread** that waits for some particular event to happen (e.g., a user has input some data to stdin). Meanwhile, the main program is doing something but at some point it suspends its execution until it receives a signal.

The **signal** may come from the thread because it has detected the **event** or it may be due to a **timeout** because I don't want it to wait for ever.

I have made some code but it does not work as expected...

```
/*
 * This code SHOULD start a thread that gets messages from stdin.
 *  If the message is a "quit", the thread exits. Otherwise it raises
 *  a signal that should be caught by the main program.
 *  The main program simply waits for the message unless a timer of
 *  5.5 seconds expires before receiving the signal from the thread.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define BSIZE 100   /* Buffer size */

sigset_t mask;              
pthread_t tid;
//struct itimerval timervalue;

int milisec = 5500; /* Timeout: 5,5 seconds */
int end = 0;

char buffer[BSIZE];


//Function prototypes
void init(void);
void * thread_job(void *);
void message_rcvd(void);
void wait_for_message_or_timeout(void);
int start_timer(struct itimerval, int);
int stop_timer(struct itimerval);
void on_signal(int);


// MAIN: Wait for message or timeout
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    init();

    while(!end){
        wait_for_message_or_timeout();
        if(!end)
            printf("Message received [%s]\n", buffer);
    }

    return 0;
}


// INIT: Initializes the signals that the program will wait for
//       and creates a thread that will eventually generate a signal
void init()
{

    /* Init the signals I want to wait for with sigwait() */
    sigemptyset(&mask);         
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGUSR1);  
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGALRM);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL);

    //signal(SIGUSR1, SIG_IGN);
    signal(SIGUSR1, on_signal);

    /* Create the thread and put it to work */
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread_job, NULL);

}

void on_signal(int signum){
    printf("on_signal\n");
}

// THREAD CODE -------------
// THREAD JOB: When the user inputs a message, it passes the message
//              to the main thread by invoking message_rcvd()
void * thread_job(){

    int end = 0;

    while(!end){
        printf("Input message:");
        if (fgets(buffer, BSIZE, stdin) != NULL)
            message_rcvd();
    }
}

// MESSAGE RECEIVED: If message is not equal to "quit" raise a signal
void message_rcvd(){

    if(strcmp(buffer, "quit") == 0){
        exit(0);
    }else{
        printf("Going to raise SIGUSR1...");
        if(raise(SIGUSR1) == 0)
            printf("raised!\n");
    }

}


// WAIT: Should wait for signal SIGUSR1 for some time
void wait_for_message_or_timeout(){

    int sigid;  
    struct itimerval t;

    /* Set a timer to prevent waiting for ever*/
    printf("Setting timer...\n");
    start_timer(t, milisec);

    /* Put the process to wait until signal arrives */
    sigwait(&mask, &sigid);

    switch(sigid){
        case SIGUSR1:
                printf("Received SIGUSR1: Message avaible!\n");
                break;
        case SIGALRM:
                printf("Received SIGALRM: Timeout\n");
                end = 1;
                break;
        default:
                printf("Unknown signal received\n");
                break;
    }

    printf("Stopping timer...\n");
    /* Stop timer */
    stop_timer(t);
}

// START TIMER: I don't want the timer to cause the execution
//              of a handler function 
int start_timer(struct itimerval timervalue, int msec)
//int start_timer(int msec)
{

  timervalue.it_interval.tv_sec = msec / 1000;
  timervalue.it_interval.tv_usec = (msec % 1000) * 1000;
  timervalue.it_value.tv_sec = msec / 1000;
  timervalue.it_value.tv_usec = (msec % 1000) * 1000;

  if(setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timervalue, NULL))
  {
    printf("\nsetitimer() error\n");
    return(-1);
  }
  return(0);
}

// STOP TIMER: 
int stop_timer(struct itimerval timervalue)
//int stop_timer()
{
  timervalue.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
  timervalue.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
  timervalue.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
  timervalue.it_value.tv_usec = 0;

  if(setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timervalue, NULL))
  {
    printf("\nsetitimer() error\n");
    return(-1);
  }
  return(0);

}
```

Here is a typical execution of this code.

```
./signaltest 
Setting timer...
Input message:hello
Going to raise SIGUSR1...raised!
Input message:friend
Going to raise SIGUSR1...raised!
Input message:Received SIGALRM: Timeout
Stopping timer...
```

As you can see, the signal SIGUSR1 is being raised and sigwait is being unblocked. However, the code seems does not continue after the signal has been raised. (Note that I don't need a signal handler but I just added for the debugging purposes. I have blocked its execution with `sigprocmask`)

**Why is SIGUSR1 unblocking sigwait but the execution does not continue from there? Is there a way to make it continue after unblocking? This seems to work for SIGALRM but why not for SIGUSR1?**

As I said, I have been looking at tons of stackoverflow questions, online howto's, tried with different system calls (e.g., pause, sigsuspend), ... but couldn't find a way to solve this :-(

If you are wondering why I am not doing this code much simpler by not using a thread is because this is not actually the code I am implementing but just a simpler example to make my question more clear. I am actually trying to implement a network protocol API, similar to the sockets API for my own protocol.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In a multi-threaded program, `raise` sends the signal to the calling thread. But you are waiting for the signal on the other (main) thread.

Comment: You are right! @dbush pointed me to a specific solution and now it works :-) Thank you for your contribution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `SIGUSR1` signal isn't going where you think it is.

In a multithreaded program, the `raise` function sends a signal to **the current thread**, which is the `thread_job` thread in this case.  So the main thread never sees the signal.

You need to save off thread ID of the main thread, then use `pthread_kill` to send a signal to that thread.

Add a new global:

```
pthread_t main_tid;
```

Then populate it in your `init` function *before starting the new thread*:

```
void init()
{
    main_tid = pthread_self();
    ...
```

Then in `message_rcvd`, use `pthread_kill`:

```
    if(pthread_kill(main_tid, SIGUSR1) == 0)
        printf("raised!\n");
```

Also, remove the definition of `end` in `thread_job`, and remove the definition of `tid` in `init`.  These definitions mask the global variables of the same name.

Sample output:

```
Setting timer...
Input message:hello
Going to raise SIGUSR1...raised!
Input message:Received SIGUSR1: Message avaible!
Stopping timer...
Message received [hello
]
Setting timer...
test
Going to raise SIGUSR1...raised!
Input message:Received SIGUSR1: Message avaible!
Stopping timer...
Message received [test
]
Setting timer...
Received SIGALRM: Timeout
Stopping timer...
```