# Do threads continue executing when a signal arrives?

Tags: c, multithreading, signals, execution, pause

I'm writing a multi-threaded program in C, where the main() changes the behavior of some signals and then spawns more threads. The question is: do the other threads continue executing when a signal arrives, or do they pause and resume execution when the signal is handled?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait for signal, then continue execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47658347/wait-for-signal-then-continue-execution)

Comment: No, other threads are not paused. But even if they would be paused, I think this wouldn't help you.

Comment: The interaction between threads and signals is undefined by the C standard, so there is no general answer to that. Please tag your question with your operating system and/or thread standard that you are using.

Comment: I'm working with POSIX threads and on Linux 4.4. Also I'm not asking how I can pause the execution of the threads, I'm asking if the other threads are paused when a signal arrives or not, because depending on the answer I'll have to continue programming doing one thing or another. Thanks.

Comment: If the threads are all running on the same CPU, then they stop while the signal handler is running.  If they are all running on different CPUs, then only the thread receiving the signal runs the signal handler.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, multi-threading is not friendly to signals. Consider using [signalfd(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) with [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do the other threads continue executing when a signal arrives

On Linux they do because a signal is only ever delivered to one thread. Unless the signal is `SIGSTOP`, which stops all threads of a process. See [`man signal(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [`man pthreads(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) for more details (ignore LinuxThreads info related to old threads implementation).

Although POSIX does not require that, so these details are OS specific.

Comment: This is not OS-specific but required by POSIX, which specifies clearly how signal delivery interacts with threads and that signal handlers interrupt the thread that receives the signal, not the process.

Comment: @R.. POSIX spec does specify how signals are generated and delivered, true. However, it does not specify in enough details how signal delivery to one thread affects other threads of execution (it must not affect other threads) - there is no such requirement.

Comment: @R.. In other words, it could stop all threads while invoking a signal handler, and still be a POSIX-compliant implementation, wouldn't it?

Comment: No. I don't see where you think you're getting that.

Comment: @R.. What POSIX requirement such an implementation would break then?

Comment: Would changing the behaviour of SIGSTOP (with signal() from signal.h) in the main thread still stop the execution of the secondary threads when SIGSTOP arrives?

Comment: @27C256 From `man signal(7)`: _The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored._

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: (1) signal delivery in a particular thread, and (2) requirement that threads (in same or different processes) behave as if they execute concurrently, i.e. that failure of one to make forward progress doesn't observably cause others not to make forward progress.